# valueError: seek of a closed file

Tags: python, loops

I worked with SAS until now and so I am pretty new to Python and trying to write some loops. I want to import some year wise datasets and the code works fine if i run it seperately, but throws an error

```
valueError: seek of a closed file
```

when run in loop.
Here is the code below

```
Import pandas as pd
location='D:/labs_2006_2018/lab_'
ext='sas7bdat'


  for BB in range(2007,2009):
        total_file=location+str(BB)+ext
        dsn='lab_'+str(BB)
        dsn=pd.read_sas(total_file)
        dsn= reader.to_data_frame()
```

this throws an error.

```
valueError: seek of a closed file
```

and I am running on Spyder Python 3.9.13 64-bit

Comment: (1) Syntax and indentation of shown code are wrong. Test code at least for these basics before publishing it here. (2) What is `reader`? (3) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: I have tested the code and copied directly from the console. Please suggest where the indentation is wrong.

Comment: `import` must be written all lowercase and the `for` can't be indented without a statement before it which requires a following indentation.

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering ("seek of a closed file") occurs because you're reassigning the variable `dsn` inside the loop, effectively overwriting the `pd.read_sas(total_file)` DataFrame with `reader.to_data_frame()`, which doesn't seem to be defined in your provided code. Additionally, there is no need to call `reader.to_data_frame()`.

Here's the corrected version of your code:

```
import pandas as pd

location = 'D:/labs_2006_2018/lab_'
ext = 'sas7bdat'

for BB in range(2007, 2009):
    total_file = location + str(BB) + ext
    dsn = 'lab_' + str(BB)
    dsn = pd.read_sas(total_file)
    # Now you can use 'dsn' DataFrame for further processing within this loop
```

By simply assigning the result of `pd.read_sas(total_file)` to the variable dsn, you're retaining the DataFrame loaded from the SAS file. Remember that in each iteration of the loop, the dsn variable will be overwritten with the new DataFrame loaded from the next SAS file.

Comment: I will test this.. for sure

Comment: Check it as an answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, but I am missing something here that as you said it is importing only one dataset and not all the datasets like 2007 2008 and 2009, looks like it is overriding the imported dataset rather than creating a new one, how can i solve this?